How to keep a constant number of line on a page after a macro modify the sheet
I am working on a page to list mechanical part and all the possible variations of components of that part, some of this have more than 21 lines. When I use the macro the lines with value 0 are removed and I can print it but I need to keep the number of lines constant at 21. Is there an easy solution to get what I want?
I am using the 2004 version of Excel.  English is not my native language so be patient please.
This is the macro I use to hide or visualize the lines
    '=========>>
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub CheckValore()

    If ActiveSheet.Range("$n$2").Value = "FALSO" Then
        VisualizzaRighe
        ActiveSheet.Range("$n$2").Value = "VERO"
    Else
        NascondiRigheVuote
        ActiveSheet.Range("$n$2").Value = "FALSO"
    End If


End Sub

'--------->>
Sub NascondiRigheVuote()
    'Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim SH As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, LRow As Long


    Const sColonnaSi As String = "N"             '<<=== Modifica
    Const iPrimaRigaDati As Long = 4             '<<=== Modifica
    Const sColonneDaStampare As String = "A:M"   '<<=== Modifica"

    'Set WB = ThisWorkbook
    Set SH = ActiveSheet
    
    With SH
        LRow = LastRow(SH, .Columns(sColonneDaStampare))
        On Error GoTo XIT
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For i = iPrimaRigaDati To LRow
            With .Rows(i)
                .Hidden = .Cells(1, sColonnaSi) <> "si"
            End With
        Next i

        With .PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .PrintArea = Intersect(.Rows(1).Resize(LRow), _
                                   .Columns(sColonneDaStampare))
        End With
    End With
XIT:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

'--------->>
Sub VisualizzaRighe()
    ActiveSheet.Rows.Hidden = False
End Sub

'--------->>
Function LastRow(SH As Worksheet, _
                 Optional Rng As Range, _
                 Optional minRow As Long = 1, _
                 Optional sPassword As String)
    Dim bProtected As Boolean

    With SH
        If Rng Is Nothing Then
            Set Rng = .Cells
        End If
        bProtected = .ProtectContents = True
        If bProtected Then
            .Unprotect Password:=sPassword
        End If
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = Rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       after:=Rng.Cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
    If LastRow < minRow Then
        LastRow = minRow
    End If

    If bProtected Then
        SH.Protect Password:=sPassword, _
                   UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    End If
End Function

'<<=========
This is the page before:

This is after. I need that every page with info is 21 lines and every page with no fields is not printed.

desired print result

It would be useful to see sample data, as well as current and expected output. Seeing the relevant parts of your code will also help.

What if there's nothing in the lines? Can you show us what it should look like?

@cybernetic.nomad what do you mean exactly?

in any given page the macro should check if a value is higher than zero, if not the cell if removed , you can see in the secon image tha the lines numbers jump from 16 to 22, whta i need is tha every page that have any positive value data is 21 lines long
